# gprof a library - question

Tags: profiling, gprof

I need to gprof a library in our system to examine the function calls and see if we can optimize it any more. Basically, what I have is

Executable A which uses a shared Library myLib.so

I want to gprof the myLib.so. When I compile myLib.so source using -pg option, it produces a .so file just fine.

But, recompiling the Executable A against that library is not producing the *.gmon file for some reason. What needs to be done? Should I link the myLib statically? If so, please tell me how. I am a newbie, so pardon my ignorance. I am learning everyday

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[You can do better than **gprof**.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343)

You could use a good sampling profiler like [RotateRight/Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com/), or you could try [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024). Also **lsstack** serves well. **pstack** does too, but is more work for you.

Comment: Used to be a big fan of RotateRight's Zoom profiler. Haven't needed to use it in years. Today I needed it, but the web site says development stopped in 2015.  That's too bad.

Comment: @Stéphane: Sounds like they've got one foot on a banana peel.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but I think the best thing to do is to create a small C/C++ program that uses the library with some test calls, compile it with the library using -pg, and profile that.
That way you nicely isolate the profiling issues of the library from other stuff, too.

As http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/Implementation.html and https://stackoverflow.com/a/7290284/885650 point out, you need -pg when linking, as it adds extra code everywhere.